# TypeError: Float isn't subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I haven't found anything similar so.. I have 2 df's with the same Gene name but different p value's, example :

[image: pvalue-gene]
I am trying to run over combinedB values on "pvalues" column (numeric) and if they are >=0.05 to continue to combinedA values on "pvalues" column (numeric) which are <= 0.00005. **I mustn't concat them
**EDITED**

```
      df = pd.read_csv("CombinedA.csv")
df = df['pvalue']
df1 = pd.read_csv("CombinedB.csv")
df1= df1['pvalue']
for i in df1:
    if i >= 0.05:
        while True:
            for i in df:
                if i <= 0.00005:
                     print(i)
```

Now it just running non stop. I think it prints only the "df" part

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Edited, no error, just non stop run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv("Combined.csv", index_col = ["Gene"])
df = df['pvalue']
df.where(df <= 0.005, inplace = True)
df = df.replace(r'', np.NaN).dropna()

# Filter CombinedA
dfA = pd.read_csv("CombinedA.csv", index_col = ["Gene"])
dfA = dfA['pvalue']
dfA.where(dfA >= 0.05, inplace = True)
dfA = dfA.replace(r'', np.NaN).dropna()

df = df[df.index.isin(dfA.index)]
df.to_csv("CombinedRest.csv")
print(df)
```

---

This one is working.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are reading the table. You then overwrite df1 and get an array of the values.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("CombinedB.csv")
df1= df1['pvalue']
```

Here you are iterating over the array of your values. These values are of type float.

```
for i in df1:
```

You are treating your `float` value as a dictionary. This is throwing the error.

```
if i['df1'] in df1 >= 0.05:
```

You probably meant to write:

```
if i >= 0.05
```

You are repeating the same mistake a couple more times.